# System screen resolution changing on android emulator run

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, screen-resolution

I am trying to develop android application, to test the application I created one AVD. When I run the AVD my system's screen resolution changes...

Why is this happening ?

Below is the emulator settings -

[image: Emulator Settings]

Comment: You mean the resolution of your development machine changes?

Comment: Yes, resolution of my development machine changing...

Comment: Now that's really strange and I can see no reason for this. Perhaps you should file a bug against the android emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue after some time..

The problem was not of emulator or the android.

the issue was here emulator-arm.exe > properties > compatiblity

the checkbox Run in 640 x 480 is checked and this was the reason that each time I was running the emulator my screen resolution was changing. Unchecked that box and it started running as it should :)

[image]